# How to make a default instance in Ruby as in Prime class?

Tags: ruby, class, module, instance, default

I would like to make a class or maybe a module which can be loaded / required with "require" or "require_relative". However, for simplicity I don't want to instantiate any objects, just start using its methods, similar to Ruby's `Prime` class. How can I achieve this?

```
require "my_module"
puts My_module.convert("data")
```

Instead of this:

```
require "my_module"
an_instance = My_module::My_class.new
puts an_instance.convert("data")
```

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Prime.html

Comment: "...I don't want to instantiate any objects,..." seems contradictory to the title of the question. `require "my_module"; puts  My_module.convert("data")` works fine if `convert` is a module method: `module My_module; def self.convert(str)...`. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Prime` class uses the [singleton pattern](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/singleton/rdoc/Singleton.html) to achieve this behaviour, then [uses a clever trick](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/2c686723feab84e4fa8b1a08b62b3298ae8dfde0/lib/prime.rb#L96-L98) to make all instance methods appear as if they were class methods. However, I don't really see why this was done. The singleton pattern would be useful if one needed to keep some global state around, but the `Prime` class doesn't really make use of this. Some people say that singleton is the most overused pattern, and they might just be right.

I am now simply guessing that your converter does not need to keep global state around. Following this assumption, you can just use module methods to achieve the API you described. For example:

```
module MyModule
  def self.convert(data)
    MyClass.new.convert(data)
  end
end
```

You can then call this method with

```
MyModule.convert("data")
```

Comment: Good answer. I'll need some quiet time to understand the "clever trick".

Comment: Now that I think of it again, maybe the Prime class actually made use of global state some time ago and now they just keep the singleton for backwards compatibility.

Comment: @CarySwoveland it's actually not that complicated except for one thing. Every time an instance method is defined, this snippet defines a class method with the same name which just delegates to the singleton instance. Now the hard part: it uses the `Forwardable` module for this, which is meant for delegating instance methods to another object. But since we want to delegate class methods, we need to get "a level higher". This is done by obtaining the metaclass via `(class << self; self; end)` and using `def_delegator` on this, instead of the class itself.

Comment: The metaclass is the class of the class, if you will, and its instance methods are the class methods of the class. This way the delegation is done for class methods instead of instance methods.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration; it will make my research earlier. For one, I know nothing of `Forwardable`, but seems worth understanding.